# Uncaught Reference Error: function is not defined (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm teaching myself how to work with ASP.NET, and I'm trying to call a C# function in a JS function in my .aspx file.

Here's my JS section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Run() {
        alert("Running!")
        var ranking = parseInt(document.getElementById("rank").value);
        var collsize = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
        var collsafety = 
           parseInt(document.getElementById("safety").value);
        var best = PageMethods.Survey(ranking, collsize, collsafety);
        document.write(best);
    }
</script>
```

The signature of the C# function (it's embedded in the .aspx file like the JS function):

```
<script language="c#">
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Survey(int ranking, int collsize, int 
       collsafety) {
       ....
    }
```

The exact error message is: Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods.Survey is not defined.

I'm calling the Run method with a button using onclick. I know the method is entered, because the first alert happens. However, when I try calling Survey, I get the error.

I've already read a couple of answers, like this: [jquery PageMethod saying the method does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854712/jquery-pagemethod-saying-the-method-does-not-exist), but the suggested AJAX didn't work either. I also read this: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/561226/errorpluspageMethodplusisplusundefined but I can't see what I'm not doing right...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work since you are embedding the c# code directly on the aspx file. Embed it on the aspx.cs file instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Survey(int ranking, int collsize, int 
   collsafety) 
  {
     return "Hello";
  }
```

You can call it via PageMethods:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Run() {
        var ranking = 123;
        var collsize = 123;
        PageMethods.Survey(ranking, collsize, onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Please contact administrator.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Lastly don't forget to add ScriptManager on the calling Page (Default.aspx on my example) and enable PageMethods to True:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here how it look like for further reference:

[image]

The code when I call the script on the button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Run()" />
```

Comment: I actually switched to AJAX and now it's not throwing that particular error (I hadn't done the AJAX correctly the first time). But now I'm getting a POST 404 Not Found error :(

Comment: You can do that with AJAX, but I simplified my explanation since you are asking how to call c# on js function.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what might be causing the AJAX error, by any chance? (Code in next comment - sorry about the formatting)

Comment: function Run() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Survey", "Survey.aspx")',
                data: { ranking: document.getElementById("rank").value,  collsize: document.getElementById("size").value,  collsafety: document.getElementById("safety").value },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
           $('#resultDisplay').replaceWith(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }

Comment: Try this instead: url: 'Survey.aspx/Survey'